# How to convert array to json string in javascript having indexes inside the element

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

My javascript array is :

```
 [
            "Action=Complete",
            "Echo=echotest",
            "PayerID=1675506249460924",
            "ObfuscatedAccountNumber=*********************",
            "ExpireDate=1225",
            "CardholderName=John Q. Test",
            "Address1=123 A. Street",
            "Address2=",
            "Address3=",
            "City=Orem",
            "State=UT",
            "PostalCode=84058",
            "Country=USA",
            "PaymentMethodId=630337dc-3537-4db1-bfaf-be98e838b3a5"
        ]
```

I want to convert it to

```
{
        "Action":"Complete",
        "Echo":"echotest",
        "PayerID":"1675506249460924",
        "ObfuscatedAccountNumber":"***************",
        "ExpireDate":"1225",
        "CardholderName":"John Q. Test",
        "Address1":"123 A. Street",
        "Address2":,
        "Address3":,
        "City":"Orem",
        "State":"UT",
        "PostalCode":"84058",
        "Country":"USA",
        "PaymentMethodId":"630337dc-3537-4db1-bfaf-be98e838b3a5"
    }
```

is there any way I can achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a hacky solution of mine.

```
var array = [
    "Action=Complete",
    "Echo=echotest",
    "PayerID=1675506249460924",
    "ObfuscatedAccountNumber=*********************",
    "ExpireDate=1225",
    "CardholderName=John Q. Test",
    "Address1=123 A. Street",
    "Address2=",
    "Address3=",
    "City=Orem",
    "State=UT",
    "PostalCode=84058",
    "Country=USA",
    "PaymentMethodId=630337dc-3537-4db1-bfaf-be98e838b3a5"
]

// In ES5
// Declare an empty object.
var obj = {};
array.forEach(function (str) {
   var data = str.split("=");
   obj[data[0]] = data[1];
});

OR

// In ES6
// Declare an empty object.
var obj = {}
array.forEach(str => {
    [key, value] = str.split("=")
    obj[key] = value
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map` function which will return an array.That array will contain the required object. Use the split function to split the string.

```js
var oldArray = [
  "Action=Complete",
  "Echo=echotest",
  "PayerID=1675506249460924",
  "ObfuscatedAccountNumber=*********************",
  "ExpireDate=1225",
  "CardholderName=John Q. Test",
  "Address1=123 A. Street",
  "Address2=",
  "Address3=",
  "City=Orem",
  "State=UT",
  "PostalCode=84058",
  "Country=USA",
  "PaymentMethodId=630337dc-3537-4db1-bfaf-be98e838b3a5"
]
// Executing same function on the element
var newObject = oldArray.map(function(item) {
  // spliting a string
  var splitValue = item.split('=');
  this[splitValue[0]] = splitValue[1]
  return this;
}, {})
console.log(newObject[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try: `JSON.stringify (yourArray);`. You can consult the documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON). Tell me if you have some questions.